# Cannot access SMB Shares from OpenIndiana server on OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, smb, opensolaris, cifs, openindiana

- I've clean installed a copy of OpenIndiana 151a (latest).
- I've imported my pools
- I've run through these directions http://blogs.oracle.com/timthomas/entry/solaris_cifs_in_workgroup_mode

I can connect to the server using my OS X Lion client with my username/password on OpenIndiana. However I do not have permissions to see the share contents, just mount it.

Permissions are user:staff 755 with no complex acls for the entire tree on the server.

If I go through terminal, i can see inside the share just fine at /Volumes/MyShare, so its only finder that is having an issue. Any ideas?

Help me SuperUser, you're my only hope!

Edit: In fact, its this issue exactly https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3193429?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: are you able to try to connect with other clients (older OS X, windows, linux)? I'm asking because the whole smb is renewed in lion, it isn't anymore based on samba - perhaps there are some compatibility problems

Comment: I've updated the question, it seems this is specifically a problem with finder somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure it's a Finder issue. Indeed, you can access your share using a terminal or another file manager. To use Finder, you can try [the solution reported here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16533316#16533316) and [here](http://www.nexenta.com/corp/forum?func=view&catid=9&id=1602&start=6#1617).

It is **a temporary fix**, but it works as in any previous versions of OSX (i.e. it survives the sleep mode etc.). I recap the solution here for the sake of documentation.

Mount CISF/SMB in "Findable" way:

1. Mount the share using Finder (e.g.cmd+K)
2. Close the Finder window
3. Turn off the network connection (eth/WiFi etc.)
4. Open a Terminal:
5. Run the command: `open /Volumes/$sharename`
6. Restart the connection
7. Open again the share with Finder and it should work as expected.

Comment: https://www.illumos.org/issues/1718 tracks the change to the illumos kernel (which OI uses) to workaround this problem.   (Contributed by the Nexenta engineers working on the problem linked to in your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The fix I originally implemented for this was to switch to using AFP. The answer above probably works though.